# Realm Swift2: Best practice for model and Realm model class separation

Tags: swift2, realm

I just have started working with Realm for Swift. After reading the documentation, still I have a couple of question marks in mind.

My biggest one is, if there is a best practice for separation Model classes from Realm classes.

For example, in Java MVC projects we used DAO classes (Data Access Object classes) which were responsible for the communication with the database layer. 
Our corresponding model classes only have either the dao object injected or we used service classes for this (like CRUD operations).

If I habe a Realm “Model” class, this seems now to be everything in one. But after having the object persisted to the database, changing attributes of the object in the UI-Layer results in

> 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call
>   beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

Which brings me back to my initial though: Shouldn’t this be separated in Realm objects and model objects. Or is it OK to have "realm.write" processes in View-Classes then?

I did some research on this but the results are very vage on this.

How do you deal with this in your projects. Do you have some kind of best practice or guidance?

Many thanks in advance
John

Comment: 0
down vote
Interesting you should ask this now - I've just begun separating out the Realm Database objects into their own space and creating the equivalent of your DAOs so my app talks directly to the DAOs and they call the appropriate Realm methods. Only started it a day or so ago so will report back ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, (on the iOS side at least), there's no established best practice for abstracting the model class logic away from the actual Realm Object subclasses. That being said, I've definitely heard of apps in the past who do do this sort of logic in order to support multiple types of data frameworks.

If I were to do this, I would make a separate object class for each model implementing my own API on how to get/set data properties, and make the Realm object an internal member of this object. This object would then serve as the generic interface between my app's logic and how to save that data to Realm. That way, if I did want to swap out the data framework down the line, I could simply replace my own data object with a new one, but keep the API consistent.

In regards to that error message you posted, in order to ensure data integrity, you cannot modify a Realm object (UI thread or otherwise) unless it's in a write transaction. That being said, you could encapsulate that logic (i.e. open up a Realm write transaction on the current thread) pretty easily within that abstract object.

Comment: Thanks TiM. That helps me a lot. What you described is what I personally would prefer in terms of separating the layers. Cheers, John

Comment: Hi again @TiM, could you please explain what you meant by _make the Realm object an internal member of this object_? A very simple example would be nice too if you have time.

Comment: Hi again @Isuru! Oh wow, this is an old question! What I meant is that since you can't modify Realm `Object` instances outside of a write transaction, you would use a wrapper class to isolate that Realm specific logic. You would have a general model object that interacts with your app as usual, but that object itself holds onto the equivalent Realm `Object` internally and performs all of the Realm logic in isolation. The goal here would be to be able to remove Realm and insert another databases engine without needing to change the class's design at all. :)

Comment: @TiM I came up with something from what I gathered but I still have a couple of doubts. I opened up a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41975550/1077789) if you would be so kind to take a look at it.

Comment: @TiM Okay, re-reading your answer cleared up one doubt I had. You're creating your own getters and setters in your wrapper class for your Realm model class' properties. So if/when you have to instantiate an instance of this Realm object, do you do it directly? Or go through the wrapper class?